# save datetime to mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

hellow, 
im creating form with datetimebox easyui, like this :

```
<input id="dt" name ="po_receive" class="easyui-datetimebox" name="date_time_pick" data-options="required:true,showSeconds:false" style="width:150px">
```

and i want to save it to mysql with datetime type database, but the result is 0000-00-00 00:00:00. The javascript easyui-datetimebox works perfectly fine.

this is my save data code :

```
<?php
$po_receive = $_REQUEST['po_receive'];

$sql = "insert into db(po_receive) values ('$po_receive')";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
if ($result){
    echo json_encode(array(
        'id' => mysql_insert_id(),
        'po_receive' => $po_receive
    ));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('errorMsg'=>'Some errors occured.'));
}

?>
```

but the result is 0000-00-00 00:00:00, is that because datetimebox value format is "01/03/2016 07:53:09" ? example datetimebox :[datetimebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqk24.png)

Comment: echo $sql to confirm value is comming right?

Answer (score 1):

you need to reformat the date before inserting to DB

```
$dc=date_create($po_receive);
$formated_date=date_format($dc,"Y-m-d"); //"Y-m-d" is the date format
$sql = "insert into db(po_receive) values ('$formated_date')";
```

Please see this link, for different types of date format
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

ok, tq guys its work. i need put function date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime())

Tq all.

Answer (score 0):

> the result is 0000-00-00 00:00:00, is that because datetimebox value format is "01/03/2016 07:53:09"

That's because you're trying the insert the datetime in an incorrect format. MySQL's `DATETIME` takes the following format, `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Here's the reference:

- [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

Use `createFromFormat()` and `getTimestamp()` methods of `DateTime` class to convert your time into unix timestamp, and then use `strftime()` to convert the unix timestamp to MySQL format.

Here are the references:

- [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

So your code should be like this:

```
<?php

    $po_receive = $_REQUEST['po_receive'];
    $unixdatetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $po_receive)->getTimestamp();
    $po_receive = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$unixdatetime);

    $sql = "insert into db(po_receive) values ('$po_receive')";
    $result = @mysql_query($sql);
    if ($result){
        echo json_encode(array(
            'id' => mysql_insert_id(),
            'po_receive' => $po_receive
        ));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('errorMsg'=>'Some errors occured.'));
    }

?>
```

**Sidenote:** Please don't use `mysql_` database extensions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions instead. And this is [why you shouldn't use `mysql_` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your input date as per MYSQL datetime standard.

**Replace:**

```
$po_receive = $_REQUEST['po_receive'];
```

**With:**

```
$po_receive = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($_REQUEST['po_receive']));
```